# Setting up python environment - modules not found after installation

Tags: python, installation, sqlalchemy, virtualenv, python-module

I'm setting up my environment for a python project, and so far the modules that I've needed to run the server I'm using (outside code) are sqlalchemy, flask, and psycopg2

After installing virtualenv, pip, and all of these modules -- I opened up a new terminal window, cded into my directory, and it seems like I'm back to square one.

It tells me "No module named sqlalchemy" (which is the first module it looks for)
and when I try to reinstall it with virtualenv, it tells me I don't have virtualenv activated

I'm in the directory /Users/chloe/Virtualenvs/sqlalchemy-workspace/project ---
so I don't understand why it thinks I don't have virtualenv or sqlalchemy (I saw both installations run green from within this directory before)

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?
I've run source ~/.bashrc to update as well

error statements:

```
ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy
Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to activate virtualenv

```
source bin/activate
```

in You VENV directory, and using pip install modules that You need.

Comment: Good answer. You might also consider using virtualenv wrapper or pyenv local if you want to automatically activate your environment when you visit the project folder